# Reading from a CSV file and using the data to talk to pygame

Tags: python, csv

Having a lot of problems with everything today it seems, first time asking a question and I can't even get my code on here correctly!

Essentially what I'm hoping to do, is to import data from a csv file and use it to select and display images using pygame e.g.

```
screen.blit(row[0],(0,0))
```

Where row[0] is Rat1 in the csv file, which has been defined in my code as:

```
Rat1 = pygame.image.load('Rat1.jpg').convert()
```

However this throws up "argument 1 must be pygame.Surface, not str", which is fair enough, but I'm really struggling to find a way around this and have found some rather bizarre goings on, bizarre to me at least.

I'm new to this, so the best way I can think to get around this, is to change the row[0] in the csv file to 1, and then to import that to my program and create an integer variable from it, e.g.

```
x = row[0]
int(x)                     
if x == 1:
    x = Rat1
```

and then plug x in to pygame, e.g.

```
screen.blit(x,(0,0))
```

This works if I just have x = Rat1 as a global variable, however doing it as above doesn't change x to = 1, it stays as row[x] so it just doesn't like it.

It boils down to this happening when I tried to test it a bit...

```
import csv

out = open("CSVTest.csv","rb")
data = csv.reader(out)
data = [row for row in data]
out.close()

print row[0]    #this causes it to print a 1, so I know
                #it's working and reading as it should

x = row[0]      #make a variable

int(x)          #doesn't throw up an error, so I assume it
                #has changed the csv string to an integer

print x         #prints a 1 again

if x == 1:
print "hello?"      #doesn't print, so clearly doesn't
                    #recognise x as an integer

if x == 49:         #I'm getting desperate now, ASCII 1?!
print "hello?!"     #No joy
```

So what on earth is it, it doesn't seem to be your standard string, as won't convert obviously in to an integer.

I've tried pygame.image.fromstring(), where the answer probably lies, but I can't get it to work.

Can anyone point out what is wrong with it all and how I can easily call data from a csv file and at least get it recognised as an integer or even better, inserted in to a bit of pygame code and displayed?

I've read things from csv files and displayed images with pygame without a hitch, but getting the two to mate seems tough, beyond me certainly.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

[`int()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int) is the Python standard built-in function to convert a string into an integer value. You call it with a string containing a number as the argument, and it returns the number converted to an actual integer:

```
print int("1") + 1
```

The above prints `2`.

If you know the structure of your list (that it simply contains lists, only one level), you could do this:

```
T2 = [map(int, x) for x in T1]
```

**Or...**

Try this.

```
x = "1"
```

x is a string because it has quotes around it, but it has a number in it.

```
x = int(x)
```

Since x has the number 1 in it, I can turn it in to a integer.

To see if a string is a number, you can do this.

```
def is_number(var):
    try:
        if var == int(var):
            return True
    except Exception:
        return False

x = "1"

y = "test"

x_test = is_number(x)

print(x_test)
```

It should print to IDLE True because x is a number.

```
y_test = is_number(y)

print(y_test)
```

It should print to IDLE False because y in not a number.

Comment: Thanks very much for the reply, I don't quite understand the T2 = [map(int, x) for x in T1] part, so I'll have to go through everything more slowly later.

The thing that gets me is that it keeps saying it is a string that is being read from the csv, it should be... "1" and I can print it as such, but it just won't allow me to convert it to an integer, which seems really odd, it's some other kind of weird format?